# Trying to copy and paste to another worksheet using VBA, but when it pastes it just pastes white space

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am having trouble figuring out an issue within my VBA code. My excel workbook involves two worksheets. One named "Database" and the other is "Picked". Using a User Form, someone can input their data into the database. Once the order is completed they click a button called "Picked". When they click this button I want it to copy the row that is selected in the form (from the Database sheet), and then paste it into the next empty row in the "Picked" sheet.

```
Private Sub cmdPicked_Click()

 Dim iRow As Long

  If Selected_List = 0 Then

    MsgBox "No row is selected.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Delete"
    Exit Sub
  End If

Dim i As VbMsgBoxResult

i = MsgBox("Has this item been picked?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation")

If i = vbNo Then Exit Sub


If frmForm.txtRowNumber.Value = "" Then

Else

    iRow = frmForm.txtRowNumber.Value
    
End If

iRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 0), _
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A:A"), 0)

Rows(iRow).Copy
Worksheets("Picked").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert

 
iRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.lstDatabase.List(Me.lstDatabase.ListIndex, 0), _
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A:A"), 0)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Rows(iRow).Delete 'Delete



Call Reset

MsgBox "Selected item has been picked.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Completed"

End Sub
```

When using this code, it does not paste the values from the selected database row into the next empty cell in the picked sheet. All it does is paste a blank white row. Please help me out if you can! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Rows(iRow).Copy` needs to be qualified with the appropriate `Worksheet`: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Rows(iRow).Copy` presumably.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, it worked! My internship is saved!